# "The remote certificate was rejected by the provided RemoteCertificateValidationCallback." error when QuickFix/n tries to connect

Tags: ssl, fix-protocol, quickfixn

I am using Quickfix/n to connect to to server using SSLProtocols=Tls11, but I get the error message "The remote certificate was rejected by the provided RemoteCertificateValidationCallback."

According to the documentation the following SSL versions are supported: SSLv2, SSLv3, TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1.

If SSLProtocols=Tls or SSLProtocols=Tls11, I get the error below:
screenshot:https://prnt.sc/IT2Ymm9w44Fn

stacktrace:
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.SendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken message, ExceptionDispatchInfo exception)
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.CompleteHandshake(SslAuthenticationOptions sslAuthenticationOptions)
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.d__175`1.MoveNext()
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslClientAuthenticationOptions)
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(String targetHost, X509CertificateCollection clientCertificates, SslProtocols enabledSslProtocols, Boolean checkCertificateRevocation)
at QuickFix.Transport.StreamFactory.SSLStreamFactory.CreateClientStreamAndAuthenticate(Stream innerStream) in C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Repos\QuickFixN\QuickFIXn\Transport\StreamFactory.cs:line 262

message:
The remote certificate was rejected by the provided RemoteCertificateValidationCallback

If SSLProtocols=Ssl2 or SSLProtocols=Ssl3, I get the error below:
screenshot:https://prnt.sc/DTsuHJg1S6jF

stacktrace:
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.d__175`1.MoveNext()
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslClientAuthenticationOptions)
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(String targetHost, X509CertificateCollection clientCertificates, SslProtocols enabledSslProtocols, Boolean checkCertificateRevocation)
at QuickFix.Transport.StreamFactory.SSLStreamFactory.CreateClientStreamAndAuthenticate(Stream innerStream) in C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Repos\QuickFixN\QuickFIXn\Transport\StreamFactory.cs:line 262

message:
Authentication failed, see inner exception.

My config file:

```
[DEFAULT]
ConnectionType=initiator
ReconnectInterval=20
FileStorePath=.\FIXLogs\
FileLogPath=.\Logs\
DebugFileLogPath=.\DebugLogs\
StartTime=00:00:00
EndTime=00:00:00
UseDataDictionary=Y
DataDictionary=./FIX44_PrimeXM.xml
ResetOnDisconnect=Y
BeginString=FIX.4.4
HeartBtInt=30
ScreenLogShowEvents=Y
TimeZone=Central Europe Standard Time
# UseLocalTime=Y
MillisecondsInTimeStamp=Y
ValidateFieldsHaveValues=N

[SESSION]
SessionQualifier=TRADESESSION
SocketConnectHost=varianseuk.primexm.com
SocketConnectPort=xxxxx
TargetCompID=xxxxx
SenderCompID=xxxx
ResetOnLogon=Y
SSLEnable=Y
SSLProtocols=Ssl3
```

How can I fix this error?